# How can I call a swig python function when a parameter is using typedef int

Tags: python, swig, typedef

I have a C++ API I'm trying to wrap in Python.There is a function **Foo(TAPIINT32 &iResult)** with **typedef int TAPIINT32** in header file.When I use:
**a=0**
**mymodule.Foo(a)**
in python to call it,I get an error as "**TypeError: in method 'Foo', argument 1 of type 'TAPIINT32 &'**".Is anybody could help with this?Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SWIG needs to be told when parameters are outputs and has pre-existing typemaps to help.  Here's an example:

**api.h**

```
typedef int TAPIINT32;
void Foo(TAPIINT32& iResult);
```

**api.cpp**

```
#include "api.h"

void Foo(TAPIINT32& iResult)
{
    iResult = 5;
}
```

**api.i**

%module api

```
%{
#include "api.h"
%}

%include <windows.i>
%apply int* OUTPUT {TAPIINT32t&};
%include "api.h"
```

The `%apply` command tells SWIG to apply an existing typemap to the indicated type.  In this case, the pre-existing `int* OUTPUT` typemap is applied to all `TAPIINT32&` parameters.  Note that the OUTPUT typemap suppresses the need for passing a parameter, and returns it as an additional return value instead.

Output:

```
>>> import api
>>> api.Foo()
5
```

Comment: Thank you very much.It solved this problem perfectly.